# iOS Bluetooth characteristic write without response

Tags: ios, bluetooth-lowenergy

I have this code to write value to characteritic of a bluetooth device:

```
CBPeripheral *speaker = ...;
NSData *data = ...;
CBCharacteristic *chara = ...;
[speaker writeValue:data forCharacteristic:chara type:CBCharacteristicWriteWithResponse];
```

data value is:

```
(lldb) po data
<02080101 a800e001>
```

chara has the following properties:

```
CBCharacteristicPropertyRead
CBCharacteristicPropertyWriteWithoutResponse
CBCharacteristicPropertyWrite
CBCharacteristicPropertyAuthenticatedSignedWrites
```

This code works fine, and the speaker shows the new value, when using type CBCharacteristicWriteWithResponse, but does not work with type CBCharacteristicWriteWithoutResponse.

What could be the reason for that?

Answer (score -1):

just 
only one can work
it depends on your characterstic.properties Property

Declaration
SWIFT

```
struct CBCharacteristicProperties : RawOptionSetType {
    init(_ rawValue: Int)
    init(rawValue rawValue: Int)
    static var Broadcast: CBCharacteristicProperties { get }
    static var Read: CBCharacteristicProperties { get }
    static var WriteWithoutResponse: CBCharacteristicProperties { get }
    static var Write: CBCharacteristicProperties { get }
    static var Notify: CBCharacteristicProperties { get }
    static var Indicate: CBCharacteristicProperties { get }
    static var AuthenticatedSignedWrites: CBCharacteristicProperties { get }
    static var ExtendedProperties: CBCharacteristicProperties { get }
    static var NotifyEncryptionRequired: CBCharacteristicProperties { get }
    static var IndicateEncryptionRequired: CBCharacteristicProperties { get }
}
OBJECTIVE-C
typedef enum {
   CBCharacteristicPropertyBroadcast = 0x01,
   CBCharacteristicPropertyRead = 0x02,
   CBCharacteristicPropertyWriteWithoutResponse = 0x04,
   CBCharacteristicPropertyWrite = 0x08,
   CBCharacteristicPropertyNotify = 0x10,
   CBCharacteristicPropertyIndicate = 0x20,
   CBCharacteristicPropertyAuthenticatedSignedWrites = 0x40,
   CBCharacteristicPropertyExtendedProperties = 0x80,
   CBCharacteristicPropertyNotifyEncryptionRequired = 0x100,
   CBCharacteristicPropertyIndicateEncryptionRequired = 0x200,
} CBCharacteristicProperties;
```

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question, you're just posting the implementation for the `CBCharacteristicProperties` enums.

Comment: I already show that It is just work only one way,you have known your chara property only support the type .WithoutResponse,it will only work in this type,if your ble support .withresponse, you can  use this func didWriteValueForCharacteristic to check if your data is send well.